# UITableViewCell containing UIStackViews use lots of memory

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

Usually, my app uses around 50MB of RAM at the most, but I recently noticed that RAM usage was over 100MB.

This happens on a `UITableViewController`. I have a prototype cell with an `UIImageView`, and beside it, a `UIStackView` which contains two labels, and another `UIStackView` containing a `UIImageView` and `UILabel`.

After investigating, I found that it was the `UITableViewCell`, and more specifically when I have a `UIStackView` within it. When I load more cells, the memory goes up even higher. I'm not even doing any modification to the cell in `cellForRowAt:`, and I've tested this with a separate cell just to make sure, and I had the same issue.

Instruments shows that there are no memory leaks.

I'm using Xcode 9 Beta 5 and Swift 4.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: your `cellForRowAt` code? are you reusing cells?

Comment: Just `tableview.dequeueReusableCell` and then returning it.

Comment: Are you sure its causing by your stackview but not your image? If your image is huge then maybe thats the reason

Comment: No, it is definitely not. I set the images in `cellForRowAt` and I've gotten rid of everything other than the code for loading the cell.

Comment: @dfd `UIStackView` and `UITableView` are very different.  I can see a case for replacing `UITableView` with `UICollectionView` but not with `UIStackView`

Comment: @dfd: `UIStackView` is at most an alternative for static table views. `UITableView` is very memory efficient, especially for large tables, but this does not apply to `UIStackView`.

Comment: Which objects does Instruments display as the largest memory consumer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the issue was actually was with the code I was using for dynamic cell heights in the `UITableView`. So, it has been fixed.